# Power electronics on a PCI/PCIe expansion card

Tags: power-electronics, mains, safety, switching, computers

I'm not sure if its been done before but how feasible is the idea of building an computer expansion card (PCI/PCIe) that carries mains power on some areas of the expansion card being switched by relays, TRIACs or IGBTs mounted on the board that talks to a controller on the board and/or the PCI bus to the computer for power, command, control and data acquisition? The closest thing I have found is the [PCIE-1765](https://www.advantech.com/en-sg/products/1-2mlkb0/pcie-1765/mod_5aca90a8-7696-4ceb-9d94-b16ceeb111cb) by Advantech.

[image]

It has a few relays and tantalum capacitors which seems geared towards interfacing with power systems and electronics. But however what I want is the metal slot at the back serve as connectors for the mains power. Mains power to the board would be carried in using power connectors such as a female IEC C7 connector which is compact enough not to exceed the slot height, and I envision a power input and output connector for source and destination [image]

Apart from the obvious electrical safety issues (assuming certain precautions like mains power isolation and proper earthing will be undertaken, to make matters worse, IEC C7 does not have an earth connector), is there a reason why such power electronics switching devices cannot be or would have challenges implemented on a computer expansion board?

Comment: It seems a bad idea to introduce mains into an environment where a user would normally be able to poke their fingers around with zero risk of electric shock.

Comment: If your goal is to switch relays it would be orders of magnitude easier to use USB, which you could then electrically isolate from the PC which would also be safer.  From my point of view, using PCIe is unnecessarily complex and harder to make safe.  Is there a technical reason to prefer PCIe?

Comment: Have you considered PXI, basically a PCI bus in an industrial chassis. https://www.ni.com/en-us/shop/category/switches.html?productId=118775

Comment: @Mattman944 yes, industrial chassis might be needed. Common for SCADA control systems. Migrating a desktop PC chassis to an industrial chassis isn't too difficult and definitely worth the effort in terms of safety

Comment: You technically could, but it does seem like a bad idea. Note that PCs are sometimes operated with the case open, and even when the case is closed, there is absolutely nothing between your circuit board and a bunch of other parts that aren't intended to be next to high voltages. Maybe you could design it with physical protection, but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked card is for a DAQ rack where potentially hv measurements can also be present. It is not a pci card for a PC. (personal computer) But for specialty gear.

Aside from the safety challenges:

- Risk of shock.
- The need for multiple mains sources.

There will also be significant EMI challenges:

- Switching noise of the relays.
- Conducted noise from the attached signals.
- Transient immunity? What if it sparks to a sata cable nearby?

Comment: Where do you see that the advantek card is not intended to be installed in a PC? I certainly can't find anything stating that in it's user guide or data sheet.

Comment: @PeterGreen it uses a PCIe standard but for high power use one would expect the PC to be custom built or at least migrated to a more suitable enclosure such as an industrial chassis which materials used are more rugged than a home-based PC casing, with more earthing capabilities and better airflow? That's  probably what the designers had in mind

Answer (score 5):

To me there are several concerns with having hazardous voltages exposed on a PCIe card.

1. It violates the "principle of least surprise". People don't expect the inside of a PC to be an electrically dangerous environment. Some PCs don't even need any tools to open the case.
2. You don't know what will be in the next slot over or how rigid the case will be, or what other equipment will be installed in the case, so it's basically impossible to be sure what the creepage and clearance distances will be between circuitry on your card and circuitry on the next card over.
3. What connectors to use, Ok so a figure 8 inlet fits, but a figure 8 inlet has no provision for a protective earth connection and is only suitable for use as an Inlet connector, it's definitely not suitable for use as an outlet connector. Most other mains connectors have no hope of fitting on a PC back plate.

That said, I think with enough effort an approach similar to that used by some dial-up modems could be taken where a rigid insulating shell is screwed to the card, covering up any exposed connections that may carry hazardous voltages.

That advantek card is ringing alarm bells for me. It feels like someone has copied the voltage ratings from the datasheet for the relays to the datasheet for the product containing the relays, without thinking through the overall safety implications.

Comment: It's ringing alarm bells for me, I wouldn't fancy 400V on a PCB inside a PC enclosure. Also, the connector is female which implies the connector on the cable is going to be male with unshrouded pins carrying that voltage.

Comment: And even if the gender was the right way round and the PCB had a shell to cover the live terminals, I wouldn't want 400V on a D sub.